# How to iterate over Outlook's reminders?

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop

Querying for `Reminder` items in `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook`, seems they're all `null`s:

```
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

namespace OutlookDotNet
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var outlook = new Application();
            int remindersCount = outlook.Reminders.Count; // 624 items, but Outlook shows 540
            int nullRemindersCount = outlook.Reminders.Cast<object>()
                .Count(reminder => reminder == null); // They're all null: 624 items :-(
        }
    }
}
```

In addition, my Outlook is showing a different number - 540:

[image: Outlook Reminders]

I'm using `Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library` (`Version` `9.6`, `File Version` `16.0.10001.10000`)

So how can I iterate over Outlook's reminders?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code to iterate over outlook's reminder.

```
    var outlook = new Application();
    int remindersCount = outlook.Reminders.Count;
    foreach (Reminder item in outlook.Reminders)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Caption);
    }
```

Based on the above code, you can get reminder's caption.

Comment: That's exactly what I did, but in your code it's called `item`, while in mine it's called `reminder`. I ran your exact code, but got `NullReferenceException`, as `item` is `null`. Is this code working for you? Could you please specify which Outlook version are you using and which DLL you're importing from?

Comment: @Tar,  I installed nuget-package- Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook. (using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;) This code works for me, which can show all the reminder captions.

Comment: It's very frustrating... I can see the `Reminders.Count` (and it's reducing by one whenever I "Dismiss" a reminder in Outlook, so it's somehow related to reality...), but the actual `item`s are `null`.

Can it happen because of some IT restrictions in my company? Can IT restrict such operations?

Comment: I am not sure if It will affect it.  Are you try the code I provided?

Comment: Yes, `item` is `null`. I'm using Office ProPlus 365. Could you please tell which version you're using?

Comment: I am using office 2016.